# .NET Core - Project compiles and run, reSharper shows lots of errors on "FileStream" and "MemoryStream" objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, resharper

I have a .NET Core project which compiles and runs without errors.

However, ReSharper (version 2017.1.2) throws up a number of errors throughout the project, mostly related to `stream` objects.

For example:

> Cannot convert source type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to target type 'System.IO.Stream'

and when reading a stream

> Module 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0 {snip}' should be referenced

I think it's related to the latter error, however as everything runs it's just frustrating that I can't track it down.

Or should I just get ReSharper to ignore these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue in ReSharper 2017.1.3 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464676.

Comment: As a note, the EAP download as of the 10th June 2017 has fixed this issue.