# Mongodriver (c#/.netcore 2.0) able to return single documents but not whole collections as a list

Tags: c#, mongodb

For a single document, I am able to return and deserialise a value as below:

```
 public IPlayer FindById(BsonObjectId id)
        {
            var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", id);
            var player = _collection.Find(filter).Single();
            var deserialisedPlayer = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<PlayerDto>(player);
            return deserialisedPlayer;
        }
```

Previously when I've wanted to return and deserialise an entire collection of documents as a list, I've been able to do so as:

```
 public async Task<string> GetRiskLevelAggregatedTotal(int int1, string string1, string string2)
        {
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Eq("LastSnapshotData.String1", string1) &
                         builder.Eq("LastSnapshotData."+ string2 + ".Example.Id", int1);
            var result = await _patientCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();


            return result.Count.ToString();
        }
```

However when attempting something similar in a .netcore 2.0 project:

```
 public List<IPlayer> FindAll()
        {
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Eq("name", "Lorem Ipsum");
            var allPlayers =  _collection.Find(filter).ToList();

            return allPlayers;
        }
```

I get the following:
[System.Private.Corelib issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HINx0.jpg)

Thinking maybe the toList is now implicit when returning multiple documents I tried omitting it and simply using the return value of the find, but this just returns a IFluentFind definition. Is there something missing from my framework set up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deserializing the objects in a separate operation, why not declare your collection with your type, so you might have something like:

```
IMongoCollection<PlayerDTO> _collection
```

And then it's just a case of using linq to query it, the deserialization is done for you

See this post for more information on basic use of Find in C#

[MongoDB and C# Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find/40171761#40171761)

Comment: This was the first solution I tried - it still won't allow itself to be converted to a list:

Comment: IMongoCollection<PlayerDto> collection = _database.GetCollection<PlayerDto>("players");

            var playerList = collection.Find(x => true).Limit(10).ToList();

Comment: By any chance are you using resharper?

Comment: I am indeed. Could this be causing the 'System.Private.Corelib' issue seen above?

Comment: The reason i asked was because I came across this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300609/net-core-project-compiles-and-run-resharper-shows-lots-of-errors-on-filestr?rq=1

Comment: That does seem to have been the issue, thanks pieperu!